# The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_sendTransaction without a callback parameter

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I have a payable function in smart contract named 'gameDeposit' where user need to deposit eth to  participate in game but when I call it using web3 javascript api 
it gives me uncaught error

```
inpage.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_sendTransaction without a callback parameter
```

```
        const Abi = [{ABI}];
        const contractAbi = web3.eth.contract(Abi);
        const myContract = contractAbi.at("0x3....");
        const amountEth = '0.01';
        console.log(myContract);
        const gameID = '10';
        myContract.gameDeposit(gameID).send({
            from: web3.eth.accounts[0],
            value: web3.toWei(amountEth, 'ether')
        },(error , result) => {
            if(!error)
                console.log(result);
            else
                console.error(error)
        })
    })
```

Comment: I'm calling this function on a button click

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 3):

I've got the solution. there should no parameter in gameDeposit function , parameter should be in .sendTransaction().

```
     myContract.gameDeposit.sendTransaction(gameID,{
            from:   web3.eth.accounts[0],
             value: 1000000000000000
         },function(error , result){
             if(!error)
                 console.log(result);
             else
                 console.log(error.code)
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

@Chitranshu answer is quite right (works just fine), but you can have the parameter on gameDeposit as long as you include the callback function within. See below:

```
myContract.gameDeposit(gameID,{
        from:   web3.eth.accounts[0],
         value: 1000000000000000
     },function(error, result){
         if(!error)
             console.log(result);
         else
             console.error(error);
    });
```

This way it automatically determines the use of call or sendTransaction based on the method type.